# Firefox Add-on SDK: Is it possible to disable loading some resources on page?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, selenium-firefoxdriver

Is it possible to disable loading some resources via url matching in Firefox Add-on SDK, Javascript API?

For example, I want to disable load any resources from 'googleapis.com' on my page.